# What does 違う mean in this "なんか違うわよね、これ"

Tags: meaning

> 「この馬鹿！いきなりあんなことして、責任取りなさいよねっ！」
>
> 「もちろんだ。お前を嫁として迎えさせて欲しい。」
>
> しまった、こいつって、こういうやつだった…
>
> 確かに責任取りなさいって言ったのは私だけと…**なんか違うわよね、これ**…
>
> でも…
>
> 「ふ、ふん。いいけど、報いは受けてもらうわよ。」

I'm not quite sure what she means by なんか違うわよね、これ towards the end of this excerpt. It's clear that she didn't expect him to agree straightaway(or rather she had forgotten that he was the kind of guy who would do that). I think the "なんか違うわよね、これ" is referring to how he said "「もちろんだ。お前を嫁として迎えさせて欲しい。」" which doesn't "fit in" with how this situation should play out(which then led to her adding on him receiving a punishment). Is this the correct way to understand this or can somebody else add any insight?

Comment: Isn't 私だけと a mistype of 私だけ**ど**?

Answer (score 1):

Your understandng of the passage seems correct.

> 「なんか違{ちが}うわよね、これ・・」

This usage of 「違う」 might not actually be found in a smaller dictionary.  Here, it means "***odd***", "***unusual***", etc.  It is used when something did not turn out the way one would normally have expected it to.

「これ」, I would say, refers to the peculiar flow of this conversation in which the woman calls the man an idiot and demands an apology and even further actions from him for what he has done, but the man just abruptly proposes to her instead.  (I will not ask what he did as minors might be reading this.)